# Фреймы и Body

Tags: html

Я хочу спросить, если мне надо, чтобы шапка загружалась тегом `<img>`, а сама страница фреймом, то как это отразить в коде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style='background-image: url(/path/yourimage.jpg); height: 200px'>Ну, типа, шапка</div>
<iframe src="somepage.html">
Идите нафиг с браузером, который айфреймы не умеет отображать
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: из за совместимости доктайпов можно писать не <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> а просто <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: лучше так, как я написал. Проблем с ИЕ будет меньше.